# UIButton in custom UITableViewCell stop working after rotation

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, rotation, orientation

Problem:

I used custom UITalbeViewCell that contains two buttons, they work fine in the portrait orientation. After the rotation, they all stop responding to the button touch up inside function. Some people having problems that their buttons couldn't drew correctly after rotation. Mine looked fine since the buttons are showing in the right places after rotation, but they do not respond to the button press anymore.

For this specific view in my app, I used a UIPageController to implement multi pages in a view, and for the view (name it EmbeddedView for now) embedded in the page's scroll controller, there is a UITableView that contains custom UITableViewCell. Custom table view cell only has a nib, the file's owner is EmbeddedView.

in EmbeddedView:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
/*===== This is the most memory efficient way of creating table view cells =====*/

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    [[self customTableCellNib] instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
    cell = [self customTableCell];
    [self setCustomTableCell:nil];
    }
}
```

What I tried:

I created another nib file for the custom table view cell and used it in  -cellForRowAtIndexPath(), I checked the orientation and dynamically create the cell by using different nib, no luck.

I added [tableview reloadData] in -didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(), didn't do anything.

Would someone point me to the right direction please? Any help is appreciated.

This is the table view Autosizing in IB:

[image]

It looks right but the buttons are not working

[image]

Update: I tried to specify different Autosizing masks in IB for the table view, and the results are showing below:

<1>

[image] [image]

[image]

<2>

[image] [image]

[image]

<3>

[image]

[image]

<4>

[image]

[image]

Comment: just add touch up inside Event of UIbutton in cellForRowAtIndexPath() method then check.

Comment: @DixitPatel: Thanks man, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Does the button get pressed visually?  What I mean is do you see the "down" state of the button change when you press it? (it should turn dark by default).

Comment: I'd like to help but I have no clue of why that would work like that. The only thing that I would do is to try different stuff. Can you start a clean project and try to reproduce just that? Also, check if the superview is sizing correctly (check the view hierarchy btw).

Comment: You're using a UIPageViewController or a UIPageControl? Please explain your view/controller hierarchy.

Comment: @FábioOliveira, it is a UIPageControl, it is just like the PageControl sample app Apple provided. I used the one for phone version, not the iPad one. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: @RaymondWang so you got the code before they've updated as a Universal app? Also, which versions are you trying to support?

Comment: @FábioOliveira, this is a iPad only app but I am using the multi page thing they provide with iPhone since this suites our needs better. It works perfectly in the portrait mode.

Comment: Ok. Regarding my tip to start a clean project I'd say you take the example they have for iPad (Universal but still) and test it there. If it works you can check what's different and what's not or start back from there. Still, check my answer.

Comment: @FábioOliveira,the view hierarchy would be, View A(the page container) is pushed by a navigation controller, it is a normal view controller has a UIPageControl inside along with a UIScrollView. View B(the view actually has the table view) is inside View A so for multiple "pages" in View A, there are multiple instances of View B. The UITableView is a control in View B, and inside the UITableView, I used custom UITableViewCell which contains UIButtons.

Comment: @FábioOliveira, thanks. I've already did all of the things you said and nothing changed. I'll mark your answer +1 for now. I appreciate your help.

Comment: What I normally do in cases like of unexpected behavior in resizing and such is to change every view in the hierarchy to a different, well recognizable, color. Right now you have view A and view B with the same background color (or clear) and you don't see if view B is resizing well. Good luck.

Comment: @FábioOliveira, hey man, after coloring different view I found the reason was the frame size of page container didn't got resized properly even through the scroll view content size is. That's why even I could scroll and looks like the container size is correct but it is actually not. If you could edit your answer and put your tips together so it can help somebody with the same issue, I'll mark your answer and give you the rest 25 credits. thanks man.

Comment: @RaymondWang, done. I thing you should also edit your question to make it clear for anyone else. Great you did it!

Comment: This is a good example where to use the reveal app or spark inspector app. One is able to inspect all the view hierarchy and see what is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked how the superview is being resized?

Check if the superview has 'clip to bounds' checked. If it is not check it. That will make the view clip its contents so you see if it is resizing ok.

I'd say the superview is not sizing correctly and because of that the touch events are not well delivered also.

EDIT - So this was the tip that could let the OP reach the solution:

> What I normally do in cases like of unexpected behavior in resizing and such is to change every view in the hierarchy to a different, well recognizable, color. Right now you have view A and view B with the same background color (or clear) and you don't see if view B is resizing well. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Fabio. 'clip to bounds' means ' clip subviews' ? As I am unable to find 'clip to bounds' property in storyboard. I've similar issue. In portrait the tableview works fine, but in landscape the right half of the tableview doesn't recognise the touches - neither the scrollview nor the button and other elements of tableviewcell.

Comment: @RaviSisodia: Yes. You may have something on top of your table view that is taking the touch events. Try the reveal app or spark inspector app. You will be able to inspect all the view hierarchy and see what is happening.